# Are Job's seven sons and three daughters in Heaven?

Tags: job

At the end of Job, God blessed him and gave him twice as much as he had in the first part of his life but he still has seven sons and three daughters.  Is it a common interpretation that his first seven sons and three daughters who were killed are alive in heaven? This would be twice as much--fourteen sons and six daughters. What are other interpretations from groups that would find the former interpretation unacceptable?

Comment: This is a common interpretation since everything else of Job's was doubled. The only problem you have are the references in Job that seem to discredit the notion of life after death.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are happy to have you participate. This is a good question, however, we generally prefer the question to be more definitely answerable. As this is now, it is dangerously close to an opinion question, because we just don't know the answer. Further, as Affable Geek pointed out, there is the issue that some Annihilationist groups will say that they are certainly not alive, unless they were resurrected. I'm going edit this to be a little more specific.

Comment: When you get a chance, you can see the [about] pages and [help] to learn how to use the site and what it is all about. There is also a meta site where we discuss policy. See [this post](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/newcomers-be-patient-you-will-get-there-if-you-follow-our-direction-keep-tryi) and the other posts linked there for specifics about site policy.

Comment: @ Affable Geek-came across this today Job ch 19 v 25-27.Like any scripture it is open to one's interpretation in the same way as the seven son's and three daughters are.

Comment: There is a [sequel to Job](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8694-job-testament-of) if you're interested!

Comment: @ Peter Turner-very interesting! reference to the children being in Heaven.

Answer (score 1):

To be absent from the body is to be present with the Lord. 2 Corinthians 5:8. Our bodies may not acend to heaven right away but our spirit (Those who have accepted Jesus Christ) goes to God immediately.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).